# Nodejs Handling Api With Undefined Json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert data from an api request to an object but my request returns an error `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0` . The payload is formatted like this ;

```
'{\"MESSAGE_HEADER\":{\"SENDING_APPLICATION\":\"EMR\",\"SENDING_FACILITY\":\"13939\",\"RECEIVING_APPLICATION\":\"IL\",\"RECEIVING_FACILITY\":\"13939\",\"MESSAGE_DATETIME\":\"20210212090359\",\"SECURITY\":\"\",\"MESSAGE_TYPE\":\"SIU^S12\",\"PROCESSING_ID\":\"P\"},\"PATIENT_IDENTIFICATION\":{\"EXTERNAL_PATIENT_ID\":{\"ID\":\"\",\"IDENTIFIER_TYPE\":\"GODS_NUMBER\",\"ASSIGNING_AUTHORITY\":\"MPI\"},\"INTERNAL_PATIENT_ID\"}'
```

I would like to remove the first and the last quote then all the `\`.

I have tried replacing the quotes with nothing but i get an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

My code looks like this ;

```
app.post("/endpoint", (req, res) => {

    var test = req.replace(/\'/g, '');

    JSON.parse(test);

    console.log(test);
```

Any recommendations on how i can handle the data will be appreciated. Also i cannot change this payload to come differently.

Comment: Your code makes it look like you are using Express and that `req` is an Express request object … so it won't be a string at all.

Comment: It *sounds* like you should solve your problem by a combination of (a) Fixing the code *making* the request so it sends valid JSON and (b) Using the standard JSON body parsing middleware that is provided as part of Express … but your code isn't very clear.